# Compare image by histogram matching

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition

I want to **compare two images** by using **histogram matching** with the method **correlation**.

[image]
[image]

Apparently, these two images are similar. Then, I try to find out the correlation with the following code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#reading the images and convert them to HSV
base = cv2.imread('base.jpg')
test1 = cv2.imread('test1.jpg')
basehsv = cv2.cvtColor(base,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
test1hsv = cv2.cvtColor(test1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Calculate the Hist for each images
histbase = cv2.calcHist(basehsv,[0,1],None,[180,256],ranges)
cv2.normalize(histbase,histbase,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
histtest1 = cv2.calcHist(test1hsv,[0,1],None,[180,256],ranges)
cv2.normalize(histtest1,histtest1,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

# Compare two Hist. and find out the correlation value
base_test1 = cv2.compareHist(histbase,histtest1,0)
print base_test1
```

However, the result printed out is just `0.05xxx`.

Why the correlation is so small?

How can I improve the result? Thank you.

Comment: what have you set `ranges` equal to? when i run your code with `ranges = None`, I get 42% similarity

Comment: @maxymoo Ops, sorry. I uploaded the wrong image for the test1. I edited and uploaded the new image. I

Answer (score 0):

When you plot the HSV histograms you'll notice two issues:

1. The histograms of these two images are **not** similar. Thus HSV histogram matching on the entire image is not a good approach to match these images or to recognize the officer.
2. The `minmax` normalization of the Saturation channel won't work well because of the large spike in the final bin of the base image.

[image: HSV Histograms]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get HSV images
base = cv2.imread("base.jpg")
test = cv2.imread("test1.jpg")
basehsv = cv2.cvtColor(base, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
testhsv = cv2.cvtColor(test, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Calculate historgrams
hist_base_h = cv2.calcHist(basehsv, [0], None, [180], [0, 180])
hist_base_s = cv2.calcHist(basehsv, [1], None, [256], [0, 256])
hist_base_v = cv2.calcHist(basehsv, [2], None, [256], [0, 256])
hist_test_h = cv2.calcHist(test, [0], None, [180], [0, 180])
hist_test_s = cv2.calcHist(test, [1], None, [256], [0, 256])
hist_test_v = cv2.calcHist(test, [2], None, [256], [0, 256])

# Plot histograms
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1)
axs[0].plot(hist_base_h, "b-", label="Hue base")
axs[0].plot(hist_test_h, "b:", label="Hue test")
axs[1].plot(hist_base_s, "r-", label="Saturation base")
axs[1].plot(hist_test_s, "r:", label="Saturation test")
axs[2].plot(hist_base_v, "g-", label="Value base")
axs[2].plot(hist_test_v, "g:", label="Value test")
axs[0].set_title("HSV Histograms")
axs[0].legend(loc="upper left")
axs[1].legend(loc="upper left")
axs[2].legend(loc="upper left")
fig.show()
```